funded by or with

My Master’s degree from the University of X, funded by the President Scholarship, enriched my learning experiences.

In the above sentence, is "funded by" appropriate? Will it be "funded with"? Or, can I use more appropriate word to express how my study was funded?

My University of X Master’s education, funded by the President Scholarship, enriched my learning experiences.

I assume the President Scholarship is the name of a scholarship program and for that 'by' is correct. However, if you were to refer to the actual scholarship i.e. the money, in which case you would need use 'President's Scholarship', than 'with' would be the more appropriate. Though, even in that case, 'by' still works.

"funded by" is generally followed by an active entity, typically an organization or person that chooses who or what to fund. So "funded by the President Scholarship" is appropriate. It's the passive version of

The President Scholarship funded my Master's degree.

"funded with" is normally followed by the material that constitutes the funding, so you might say

funded with proceeds from my GoFundMe page.

That said, you can also say "funded by my GoFundMe page", which anthropomorphizes the account.
